# How to read input from Excel in Java?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Need to extract '120%' value from excel in Java using Apache POI. I tried using CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC and CELL_TYPE_STRING which failed and result was 1.2 instead of 120%.

N: using Apostrophe (') in front of 120% works but please suggest another work around

```
 if(row.getCell(j)!=null)
 { 
    if(row.getCell(j).getCellType() ==row.getCell(j).CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC)
    {
       System.out.print(row.getCell(j).toString());
    }
    else if(row.getCell(j).getCellType() == row.getCell(j).CELL_TYPE_STRING)
     strCellValue ==System.out.print(row.getCell(j).toString());                             
    }
 }
else System.out.print("null")
```

Comment: Provide relevant piece of code.

Comment: @ManishChristian


if(row.getCell(j)!=null)
{
 if(row.getCell(j).getCellType() ==row.getCell(j).CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) 
 { 
  System.out.print(row.getCell(j).toString());
 }
 else if(row.getCell(j).getCellType() == row.getCell(j).CELL_TYPE_STRING)
 { 
  strCellValue = 
  System.out.print(row.getCell(j).toString());
 }
}
else
System.out.print("null")

Comment: Could you please add your code to your question inside code brackets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) {
    if (cell.getCellStyle().getDataFormatString().contains("%")) {
        // Detect Percent Values 
        Double value = cell.getNumericCellValue() * 100;
        System.out.println("Percent value = " + value.toString() +"%");
    } else {
        Double value = cell.getNumericCellValue();
        System.out.println("Non percent value = " + value.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what I'm trying to.. And thanks @Manish

Comment: Glad to help and please [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) the answer so other will know you get the answer.

Answer (score 0):

After checking for the type, you need to retrieve the value according to the type:

```
if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
    String value = cell.getStringCellValue();
}
```

Simply calling toString() wont't work. You code should be like this:

```
if (row.getCell(j).getCellType() == row.getCell(j).CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) {
    System.out.print(row.getCell(j).getNumericCellValue()
} else if (row.getCell(j).getCellType() == row.getCell(j).CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
    strCellValue = row.getCell(j).getStringCellValue();
}
```